# Vivino - Scraping with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape basic data about wines from Vivino. I have never done scraping before but based on some tutorials and lecture on Datacamp I tried to use basic code using library **rvest**.
However, it seems it does not work and returns zero values.
Could anyone please help me and tell me, where is the problem please? Is the code completely wrong and I should use some other method, or am I just missing something and doing it wrong?
Thank you in advance for any answers!

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwNybEOQDAQBuC3ubkG4z-abMQkIqdO00RbuTbF2_OtX1A0FHyEocAPWmPIvhh7suimga5_3YHK6qXwSWmDcvHR5ZWrKDuhhF2ypbvMC5oP96QajA%3D%3D&cart_item_source=nav-explore'
web <- read_html(url)

winery_data <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageTitle__winery--2YoIr') %>% html_text()
head(winery_data)
wine_name <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageTitle__wine--U7t9G') %>% html_text()
wine_country <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k+ .vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k') %>% html_text()
wine_region <- web %>% html_nodes('span+ .vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k') %>% html_text()
wine_rating <- web %>% html_nodes('.vivinoRating__averageValue--3Navj') %>% html_text()
n_ratings <- web %>% html_nodes('.vivinoRating__caption--3tZeS') %>% html_text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page loads dynamically, which is why `rvest` alone will not work; you also need to use `RSelenium`.

Suppose I use Firefox, the following code should work:

```
# RSelenium with Firefox
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)

# Scroll down a couple of times to reach the bottom of the page
# so that additional data load dynamically with each scroll.
# Here I scroll 4 times, but perhaps you will need much more than that.
for(i in 1:4){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(3)    
}

# get the page source
web <- remDr$getPageSource()
web <- xml2::read_html(web[[1]])

# close RSelenium
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)

# now we can go on to our rvest code and scrape the data
winery_data <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageTitle__winery--2YoIr') %>% html_text()
head(winery_data)
wine_name <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageTitle__wine--U7t9G') %>% html_text()
wine_country <- web %>% html_nodes('.vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k+ .vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k') %>% html_text()
wine_region <- web %>% html_nodes('span+ .vintageLocation__anchor--T7J3k') %>% html_text()
wine_rating <- web %>% html_nodes('.vivinoRating__averageValue--3Navj') %>% html_text()
n_ratings <- web %>% html_nodes('.vivinoRating__caption--3tZeS') %>% html_text()
```

Comment: What a great help. It works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Just one more question to be clear: you used loop: for(i in 1:4)
what does exactly mean 1:4? or other way: what would change if I used 1:10 for example? What is the point of this loop?
Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! Oh it means that the script scrolls down 4 times (and then waits another 3 seconds each via `Sys.sleep(3)`). First it does when `i` is 1, then when `i` is 2, then when `i` is 3 until `i` is 4, ergo four times. If you write `1:10`, then it will repeat the scrolling-and-waiting 10 times (which might even be better in your case because the page you scrape seems to be long... if it's not even a case of infinite scrolling).

Comment: When I run your code on a Mac, I get this error:

`sh: taskkill: command not found`